# «На следующий 2018-й год». Стоит ли употреблять наращение года?

Tags: даты, наращение

«На следующий 2018-й год». Употребимо ли наращение года в данном случае?

Comment: Корректно с запятой: _На следующий, 2018 год._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Корректно: **2018 год**

А. Мильчин в "Справочнике издателя и автора" перечисляет случаи, в которых наращение не ставят, в том числе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]